# /interactive flag with the at command in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, at

In Windows XP, it's possible to use the at command to launch programs (e.g. "at 5:00PM /interactive gohomefromwork.exe"). The at command also exists in Windows Server 2003 but I can't seem to run programs interactively there.

Instead, with a command of "at 5:00PM /interactive notepad.exe", notepad.exe is launched with no visible window at 5PM.

How can I get the /interactive flag to make at run the program...interactively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting CMD.EXE and NOTEPAD.EXE to start fine w/ the /INTERACTIVE switch on Windows Server 2003 Standard 32-bit Service Pack 2.

I suspect you're connected to a non-console session with Terminal Services. The programs started by Scheduled Tasks from an AT w/ the /INTERACTIVE switch will show up in session 0, which is visible only on the console (or a Terminal Services session connected to the console session).